# Can we create an index for all the columns in a table?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have been asked in an interview: "can I create index in all the columns of a table (suppose there is a table which has 20 columns, 1. can we have one index for 20 columns and also 2. can we have separate index on each 20 columns of table)".

Comment: Why not just try it yourself to find out? Whether you *can* and whether you *should* are different things of course. It also depends on the data types of the columns - you can't index CLOBs, for example - so were those specified?

Comment: Can you?  Sure (depending on things like the data types).  Should you?  Almost certainly not.

Comment: Could you explain why ?

Comment: Perhaps a strange way to see if you discuss IOTs?

Comment: In general "yes we can", most probably they wanted you to say that in this case it is better to create an "index organized table" instead a table and an index over all it's columns.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can max use 32 columns

> Columns   Per index (or clustered index)  32 columns maximum

see logical limit for reference

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm